# Resolving lower Bash script issue through shopt command

Tags: bash, scripts

How to solve the version issue of Bash in my Ubuntu?

I'm trying to execute a shell script in my Ubuntu VPN terminal.

My Bash version is:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

My shell script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
...
```

I have given permissions for it like so:

```
chmod +x _myscript.sh
ex -sc $'%s/\r$//e|x' _myscript.sh
sh _myscript.sh
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `(‘
```

which is because of lower Bash version, I found out after doing research.

The solution I found was to add this line after Bash declaration:

```
[code language="bash"] shopt -s extglob [/code]
```

I need to know where in the script i need to give the above line.

I tried just after `#!/bin/bash` in my script, but I still get the same error.

Comment: If it doesn't work as the first line after `#!/bin/bash` then I would say it isn't going to work, and you should show us your actual script?

Comment: *"unexpected token '(‘ which is because of lower bash version which i found by googling."* - no, almost certainly it's because you ran the script using `sh _myscript.sh`  -  **sh is not bash**. See [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a Bash script with the Bourne shell (`sh`), the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) gets ignored, so `sh` runs the script, not `bash`. You need to run the script like this:

```
bash _myscript.sh
```